# Unknown Column Name when Importing Table

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1054

I have just exported a table using phpMyAdmin and I have tried to import this table into my local database by importing the sql file I have just exported. After phpMyAdmin imports 330 rows of the 15,000. It says:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'font_name' in
>   'field list'

How can anything go wrong, I thought it was straight forward export/import?

I have had a look at row 330 and 331 and there isn't anything wrong within the two columns.

How can I narrow this down? What is the problem likely to be?

Thanks all for any help

### edit

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags2` (
  `font_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `tags` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Are you importing both table structure and data, or data only?

Comment: did you try a command line mysqldump ? its give the same error ?

Comment: @Pekka, yes both structure and data. I have updated question to show structure.

Comment: @Haim, wow, I tried that and it worked! Why did this work and the phpmyadmin didn't? Very strange. Maybe you could add an answer so I can select it as accepted answer.

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't a table named `tags2` missing that column? It would not have been deleted by the phpMyAdmin dump (because of the `IF NOT EXISTS`) but possibly by the mysqldump one.

Comment: @Pekka - no that table didn't previously exist. I tried this on an empty database several times. Played around with the database collation too as it had some non latin characters. But this didn't get me any where annoyingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a command line mysqldump instead of phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

In-fact the cause of this error message could be one of the following:

1) `phpMyAdmin` issue please check the admin settings like URL and data before doing the import. ( this is a common issue when you try to take import from the web admin `phpMyAdmin`)

if the setting is step one is correct please check point two and three

2) the character set in database, table, or column are not matched. so you need to do character set conversion to fix this issue. (I guess this is the issue in your case because usually the error message appear in this case)

3) privileges issue ( not so common)