# MYSQL ERROR 1064 (42000) - error in SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm importing some entries into a MYSQL table and it breaks on one of the INSERT statements with the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'reqSent', 'Your 1-on-1 Request has been sent', '&
(3996, 'reqSent', 'Your 1-on-1' at line 250
```

The SQL statements I'm importing have not been modified from when they were exported from phpMyAdmin and the relevant line is as follows:

```
(3996, 'reqSent', 'Your 1-on-1 Request has been sent', 'Seu 1-em-um pedido foi enviado. O instrutor ir&aacute; rever o seu pedido e pode aceitar, recusar ou sugerir detalhes sess&atilde;o diferente. Se o instrutor aceitar o seu pedido, ser&aacute; enviada uma factura (a menos que ele &eacute; livre consulta). Por favor pagar a factura de imediato. A sess&atilde;o n&atilde;o ser&aacute; agendada at&eacute; que voc&ecirc; paga', 31, '1', '2010-06-24 19:28:35'),
```

I'm not able to see what the error is here - can someone assist?

Comment: try using mysqldump instead phpmyadmin dump

Comment: Sure thanks - but the data has already been created and I cant go back and re-export it...

Comment: see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434255/unknown-column-name-when-importing-table

Comment: you can export with -where parameter like  : -where 'id > 3995'

Comment: Hi Haim - I get your point, but that's not an option for me - I do not have root / ssh access to that machine + a large dataset was exported and given to me as a "set", so redo-ing this would involve a larger task

Comment: Interesting - being inspired by your suggestion - I tried this - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/import-mysql-dumpfile-sql-datafile-into-my-database/ and it worked. If you like, I can give credit to you for your suggestion / pointer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest to using mysqldump instead phpmyadmin dump .

Comment: :) Thanks - although in this case, I didnt have a choice and the importation worked from the command line via a < redirect